# jQuery not working when introducing an external CSS file

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I have a PHP file, that includes an online form. The online form consists of a dropdown menu selection which powers the next dropdown menu according to the selection of the first choice. I use jquery.

When I started introducing CSS through an external file the jQuery not longer started working.

I included the external code as follows:

```
echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../library/main-style.css?version='.rand(1,1000).'" type="text/css" />';
```

In my sample code this would look like this:

```
<?php
include_once('../../library/constants.php');  
echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../library/main-style.css?version='.rand(1,1000).'" type="text/css" />';
```

My suspicion is that file constants.php contains

```
ob_start();
session_start();
```

but no error is being displayed.

My jquery code is as follows

```
<script>
function getPostcodeAdd(val) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "address-get-postcode.php",
        data:'building_street='+val,
        success: function(data){
            $("#building_postcode").html(data);
            $('select').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    });
}
```

and my html file is as follows

```
echo '<select name="building_street" id="building_street" onChange="getPostcodeAdd(this.value);">';
```

Whenever I disable the CSS line of code the jquery works fine.

Comment: Does your javascript have an `</script>` tag at the end?

Comment: and did you close your `<select>`?

Comment: @cillosis yes it does - I only included a snipped of the whole code as its too long to post here.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yeah I did... since the code is lengthy I only included a snippet

Comment: and the dot in `;".'>';` might be something to look at. Use error reporting to catch and display on PHP and check your JS console.

Comment: The reason we are bringing this up is your CSS should not stop your javascript from executing. It sounds like a tag isn't properly closed somewhere and the introduction of the `link` element confuses the DOM.

Comment: addendum to above comment `;".'>';` the single quote and the dot. Those seem to me being the problem or "a" problem. There's either a missing quote or one too many along with the dot.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I checked it with my code. Since the select is long I omitted the irrelevant parts. The code is correct. I updated my question.

Comment: @cillosis My initial suspecion was the fact that there is `ob_start();
session_start();`

Comment: if your suspicion is `ob_start();
session_start();` then delete it and see if it works. I can't offer a solution for it if that is what's causing your code to fail. Maybe there's something else causing this that isn't shown in your question.

Comment: *"and my html file is as follows"* - `.html`?

Comment: I checked all my code all tags are closed

Comment: show us how you include jQuery in your page